# poles and zeroes

Tags: passive-networks

In network theory, there is a theorem which states that all the network functions in the s-domain can be expressed as the ratio of two polynomials A(s)/B(s). The poles are defined as roots of the polynomial B(s), and zeroes are defined as roots of the polynomial A(s). Going through my book, however, I found that these definitions are not sufficient.  These definitions don't cover the all the details about poles and zeroes.

Can anyone tell me what exactly does pole, zero and residue mean in context of network analysis?

Comment: Possibly relevant reading: Design of RLC-Band Pass Filters  www.euitt.upm.es/uploaded/519/bandfilter_script.pdf

Comment: Why do you think the definitions of poles and zeroes as polynomial roots is insufficient?

Answer (score 2):

The zeros of a network function are the values of \$s\$ for which the function is zero (the numerator is zero).

The poles of a network function are the values of \$s\$ for which the function goes to infinity (the denominator is zero).

The numerator and denominator of the network function are polynomials in the complex variable \$s\$.

Using partial fraction expansion, the network function can be expressed as the sum of terms of the form:

\$\dfrac{r_i}{s - p_i} \$

where \$r_i\$ is the residue associated with the pole \$p_i\$

For example:

\$\dfrac{s + 1}{s^2 + 5s + 6} = \dfrac{2}{s+3} +  \dfrac{-1}{s+2}\$

Clearly, this network function has:

1 zero: \$s_z = -1 \$

2 poles: \$s_{p1} =  -3, s_{p2} = -2\$

2 residues: \$r_1 = 2, r_2 = -1 \$

Answer (score 1):

In network analysis, you tipically measure transfer functions (e.g. the response of an amplifier).

The definition you have of Poles and Zeroes is correct, however the definition alone is not sufficient to understand the consequences of having a pole or a zero.

Poles and Zeroes are useful to quickly draw the Bode plot of a transfer function (i.e. the module and phase of the transfer function with frequency as a variable).

Each pole gives you a -20 dB/dec slope of the transfer function, starting at the frequency where the pole equals zero. Each zero gives you a +20dB/dec slope of the transfer function, starting at the frequency where the zero equals zero.

Equivalent rules for shaping of the Bode plot can be described for the phase.

Useful link: [Bode Plot on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot)

Answer (score 0):

@Alfred has it right.  For a historical context and further reading this comes from complex analysis.  This is the same field has contour integration in it and in particular that is where the residue concept comes from.  Same math is used in fluid flow and other boundary values problems.